# Is there a workaround for value types making generic inference impossible?

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference, value-type

With a method defined as below:

```
public class Foo<T1>
{
    public void Bar<T2>(IQux<IBaz<T1, T2>> baz) { }
}

public interface IBaz<T1, T2> { }

public struct Baz : IBaz<SomeType, AnotherType> { }

public interface IQux<out T> {}

public class Qux<T> : IQux<T> {}
```

It is apparently impossible to have `Bar` infer `T2` as `AnotherType` when calling it like so:

```
new Foo<SomeType>().Bar(new Qux<Baz>());
```

This would work *if* `Baz` was not a struct. Is there any workaround when I can preserve passing `Baz` by value but also be able to infer the type in such a scenario?

Answer (score 3):

It is not generic type inference issue, but generic variance issue. `Bar` can not infer `T2` as `AnotherType` because that is not valid.

```
new Foo<SomeType>().Bar<AnotherType>(new Qux<Baz>());
```

This call is not valid because `Qux<Baz>` does not implement `IQux<IBaz<SomeType,AnotherType>>` interface, as `Bar` method requires. `IQux<Baz>` can not be casted to `IQux<IBaz<SomeType,AnotherType>>` because generic variance does not supported for value-types.

To make call valid, you need to add additional generic parameter to `Bar` method:

```
public class Foo<T1> {
    public void Bar<T2,TBaz>(IQux<TBaz> baz) where TBaz:IBaz<T1,T2> { }
}
```

Although that only make this call to be valid:

```
new Foo<SomeType>().Bar<AnotherType,Baz>(new Qux<Baz>());
```

It does not make generic type inference possible here.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the analysis in [PetSerAl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31330998). This fails not due to type inference failing to detect the type in question, but because the type in question which you want inference to infer isn't actually valid for the call. Type inference has legitimately failed to identify a valid type to use in the place of the method's type parameter.

As far as work-arounds go, it seems to me that especially since you seem to want to take advantage of the covariant type parameter in `IBaz<out T>`, making `Baz` a `class` is a good choice.

As a `struct`, the type should be immutable already. So making it into an immutable `class` instead will preserve much of the benefit of the value type semantics (a notable exception being easy array initialization). And it will allow the call to succeed, which would not be the case in your code example even if you were to provide the type parameter explicitly (as noted above and in PerSetAl's answer).